# jQueryMobile-Phonegap : Footer alignment issue in Windows8 Landscape mode

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8, footer, cordova-2.7.0

I have been working on a jQueryMobile App wrapped in phonegap with **fixed footer**.

In **windows8 phones**, while changing the orientation to landscape mode, the fixed footer is not aligned correctly in **landscape mode only**. The footer seems to have a bottom padding like behavior in landscape mode. In Portrait mode, it is aligned perfectly.

I am using jquery.mobile-1.3.2, and Phonegap 2.7.0.

I have been trying the fixes mentioned in the below URL's, but did not help:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-fixed-footer-not-at-the-bottom-on-windows-phone-7-and-8

stackoverflow.com/questions/16602585/jquery-mobile-position-fixed-in-windows-phone-8-and-viewport-height

gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/jquerymobilephonegap-hintshacks-for-windows-phone-8-0iosandroid/

Also tried some of the JS, jQM and CSS tricks, but no change affected for the footer.

A screen-shot of the page in Landscape mode is shown in the below link (You can see the black footer, even the footer text is not clearly visible):

http://goo.gl/8RICNG

For more clarity, a part of the header section is pasted below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
```

And my App footer code is:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="" class="footer-cls">

    <div align="center" class="footer-txt"><script>document.write(footerText);</script></div>
</div>
```

Can any one please help me with a perfect work around as I am stuck with this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: In windows phone it will not supported jquery mobile so it always goes hide when u scroll ..

Comment: The issue is while changing device orientation from portrait to landscape and not while scrolling.
Thanks..

Comment: data-position="fixed" doesnt work in Windows phone 8 instead use CSS to target the dom -> position:absolute;bottom:0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mainpage.xaml try changing the property

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```

to

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

This will render the app in fullscreen mode and will reset your CSS to the entire page.This might fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for your response. This fix worked great ! . Thanks a lot.